# VBNet Error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, autocomplete, backgroundworker

This is what happened: on the form load of my application i created a background worker to bind collection (*records from database filled in the dataset*) on my control. but the problem is when the i updated the records on the database it throws an error if i run this procedure again.

```
    If xControl.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim MyDelegate As New InitializeDataBinding_Delegate(AddressOf InitializeDataBinding)
        Invoke(MyDelegate, New Object() {xControl, xQuery, xPrimaryKey}) ' ERROR HERE SAYING: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
    Else
        Using ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
            Using dbAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(xQuery, ConnectionClass.ConnectionString)
                dbAdapter.Fill(ds)
            End Using

            Dim dvm As DataViewManager = New DataViewManager(ds)
            Dim iDataList As DataView = dvm.CreateDataView(ds.Tables(0))
            For Each iBind As Binding In xControl.DataBindings
                xControl.DataBindings.Remove(iBind)
            Next
            xControl.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", iDataList, xPrimaryKey)
            xControl.Properties.DataSource = iDataList
            xControl.EditValue = Nothing
            txtStatus.Text = "Ready"
        End Using
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding:

`xControl.DataBindings.Clear()`

```
If xControl.InvokeRequired Then
    Dim MyDelegate As New InitializeDataBinding_Delegate(AddressOf InitializeDataBinding)
    Invoke(MyDelegate, New Object() {xControl, xQuery, xPrimaryKey}) ' ERROR HERE SAYING: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
Else
    Using ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
        Using dbAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(xQuery, ConnectionClass.ConnectionString)
            dbAdapter.Fill(ds)
        End Using

        xControl.DataBindings.Clear() 'HERE

        Dim dvm As DataViewManager = New DataViewManager(ds)
        Dim iDataList As DataView = dvm.CreateDataView(ds.Tables(0))
        For Each iBind As Binding In xControl.DataBindings
            xControl.DataBindings.Remove(iBind)
        Next
        xControl.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", iDataList, xPrimaryKey)
        xControl.Properties.DataSource = iDataList
        xControl.EditValue = Nothing
        txtStatus.Text = "Ready"
    End Using
End If
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to avoid updation in collection while iterating it using For Each. Use simple For loop instead of For Each.

Comment: problem is solved, i only added this code before the loop xControl.DataBindings.Clear()

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a For Each loop to remove items from a diction or KeyValuePair, but you can use a regular for loop, get the key and use the key to remove the item from the list.

```
      For i As Integer = 0 To oDictionary.Count - 1
        Dim sKey = m_oDictionary.ElementAt(i).Key
        m_oDictionary.Remove(sKey)
      Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Dim index As Integer = 0
opnieuw:
        For Each F In openbestand.file
            If F.Contains("~$") Then
                openbestand.file.Remove(openbestand.file(index))
                openbestand.path.Remove(openbestand.path(index))
                GoTo opnieuw
            Else
                index = (index + 1)
            End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a loop, you need to ensure that the index is less than the Count, since the count decreases every time a key element is removed:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To dictionary1.Count - 1
    If i <= dictionary1.Count - 1 Then
        Dim sKey = dictionary1.ElementAt(i).Key
        dictionary1.Remove(sKey)
    End If
Next
```